# JSON deserialization with Gson

Tags: java, json, dictionary, gson

This is my JSON data:

```
{
  "boards": [
    {
        "board": "3",
        "title": "3DCG",
        "ws_board": 1,
        "per_page": 15,
        "pages": 11
    },
    {
        "board": "a",
        "title": "Anime & Manga",
        "ws_board": 1,
        "per_page": 15,
        "pages": 11
    },
    {
        "board": "adv",
        "title": "Advice",
        "ws_board": 1,
        "per_page": 15,
        "pages": 11
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

This is my code for deserialization:

```
JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("http://api.4chan.org/boards.json");
String jsonBoards = json.toString();
Gson gson = new Gson();
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
map = (Map<String,Object>) gson.fromJson(jsonBoards, map.getClass());
```

But it doesn't get the job done. I need a way to get the boards name, title, and all the that information for each board. When I use `map.get()`; the key is "boards" but I want a map of every board and title and so on.

Comment: The line `Map map = new HashMap();` is unecessary, as you are creating a `HashMap` object that you never use. You should change it to `Map map;` or `Map map = null;` or combine the two last lines into `Map map = (Map) gson.fromJson(...);`.

Comment: Seems like you should call `get("boards")` to get a `JSONArray` of `JSONObject`s, and then iterate through that array to get whatever data you need and put it into whatever data structures you need it in. What specific problem are you having?

Comment: The problem is that I have no idea how to do that. I'm reading through Json and Gson javadocs but still can't figure it out. I tried to use a JSONArray but i get an error. I tried this json2 = (JsonArray) map.get("boards");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a class structure that maps your JSON data. You don't need to use a `Map` anywhere, since your JSON does not represent any map!

In fact it represents an object `{...}` that contains a field called `"boards"`, which in turn represents an array `[...]` of objects `{...}`...

So the class structure that *matches* your JSON would be something like this (in *pseudo-code*):

```
class Response
  List<Board> boards

class Board
  String board
  String title
  int ws_board
  int per_page
  int pages
```

Then, in order to parse the JSON into your class structure, you just need to do this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Response response = gson.fromJson(jsonBoards, Response.class);
```

So you'll have all the data of all your boards into:

```
String nameI = response.getBoards().get(i).getName();
String titleI = response.getBoards().get(i).getTitle();
//and so on...
```